# How to use multiple custom jinja filters on an element

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have created two custom filters for my jinja template. When I try to apply both filters to one element, only one filter will work. How do I get both filters to work?

```
{{ post.content|makeimg|taguser|truncate(200)|urlize(40, true) }}
```

All but the second filter works. The first two filters are ones I made.

Here is the code for the filters:

```
@app.template_filter('taguser')
    def taguser(text):
    return Markup(re.sub(r'@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', r'<a href="/\1">@\1</a>', text))

@app.template_filter('makeimg')
    def makeimg(text):
    return Markup(re.sub(r'img([a-zA-Z0-9_./:-]+)', r'<img width="100px" src="\1">', text))
```

Example Post:

```
Hey, @john. imghttp://image.com/image.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the filters.. both filters are working as expected.

Your mistake is that you are invoking the `Markup` method twice.

The following fix worked for me (call `Markup` only in the last filter):

**Html template** (unchanged):

```
{{ post.content|makeimg|taguser|truncate(200)|urlize(40, true) }}
```

**Code**:

```
@app.template_filter('taguser')
def taguser(text):
    return Markup(re.sub(r'@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', r'<a href="/\1">@\1</a>', text))

@app.template_filter('makeimg')
def makeimg(text):
    return re.sub(r'img([a-zA-Z0-9_./:-]+)', r'<img width="100px" src="\1">', text)
```